# How would I insert a line in a file after after a pattern that is across many lines

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I would like to insert a line right after the first time this pattern appears with bash. How would I go about doing it? I want to try to use the pattern to match location/ {*}

```
    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
            # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }
```

and I want it to become

```
    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
            # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }
    location /hbnb_static
```

Thanks I'd appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a Perl one-liner:

```
perl -e '$s.=$_ while <>; $s=~s|location / \{.*?\}|$&\n    location /hbnb_static|s; print $s' inputfile
```

Some explanation:

- Slurp the `inputfile` into variable `$s`
- The `s` regex modifier makes `.` match newlines as well
- `.*?` is lazy, so it stops when encountering a subsequent `}`
- I assumed you want 4 spaces indentation in front of the inserted line too.
- Print the result to stdout

To make this into a bash script which reads STDIN or the file on the command line, and prints the modified text to stdout:

```
#!/bin/bash
perl -e '$s.=$_ while <>; $s=~s|location / \{.*?\}|$&\n    location /hbnb_static|s; print $s' $1
```

Comment: would it be possible to do it in bash as well?